# Disabling specific days in calendar view in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-calendar, calendarview

So I'm creating a doctor booking app using kotlin and I want to disable weekend and holidays in the calendar view, I couldn't achieve this  in the normal calendar view..so can you tell how or give me a resource or something to see

Comment: https://learntodroid.com/how-to-disable-dates-in-a-datepicker-for-android/#:~:text=Use%20of%20the%20Calendar%20class,value%20passed%20as%20a%20parameter

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin
you can do this

```
//to get today date 
val dateTime: Date = Calendar.getInstance().time
//to convert it to Long
val dateTimeAsLong: Long = dateTime.time
//then make maxdate  and min date as today
calendarView.minDate = dateTimeAsLong
calendarView.maxDate =dateTimeAsLong
```

then only today's date will shown

Answer (score -1):

Please first search your answer on google and only ask on stackoverflow if you can't find the answer. You must do some research before posting.

Go to this link:
https://abhiandroid.com/ui/calendarview